# requestPermissions() is not calling onRequestPermissionsResult()

Tags: java, android, permissions

Any reason why onRequestPermissionsResult() won't be called?

Say in Activity A, I have requestPermission(Permission A, Permission A code).
In Activity B, I have onRequestPermissionsResult which has an

```
  if (requestCode == PermissionA.requestCode)
```

Shouldn't this work without any issues? Or am I doing something wrong.

I checked by putting debug logs and it calls requestPermission() and shows the disclosure UI (asking to accept and deny permission) but nothing happens after I press Accept, even though it should resume whatever I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't this work without any issues?

No. If you call `requestPermissions()` for Activity A, that will trigger `onRequestPermissionsResult()` in Activity A, not Activity B.

Comment: Is there a way I can call onRequestPermissionsResult from Activity B in Activity A?

Comment: @JavaChipMocha: No. If these activities are that closely coupled, probably they should be a single activity, rather than two separate ones.

Comment: the reason I asked was because I'm trying to refactor and remove duplicate code...and avoid using onRequestPermissionsResult in two different activities. But if there is no way to do this, I guess I have no other option.

Comment: @JavaChipMocha: Have Activity A and Activity B inherit from the same base activity, where you have your `onRequestPermissionsResult()`.